# Big-query predict using sk-learn model

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have created a sklearn model at my local machine. Then I have uploaded it on google storage. I have created a model and version in AI Platform using the same model. It is working for online prediction. Now I want to perform batch prediction and store the data into big query such as it updates big query table every time I perform the prediction.

Can someone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AI Platform does not support writing prediction results to BigQuery at the moment.

You can write the prediction results to BigQuery with Dataflow. There are two options here:

1. Create Dataflow job that [makes the predictions itself](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-prediction-example).
2. Create Dataflow job that uses AI Platform to get the model's predictions. Probably this would use online predictions.

In both cases you can define a BigQuery sink to insert new rows to your table.

Alternatively, you can use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to update a BigQuery table whenever a new file appears in GCS. This solution would look like:

1. Use gcloud to run the batch prediction (`gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction ... --output-path="gs://[My Bucket]/batch-predictions/"
2. Results are written in multiple files: `gs://[My Bucket]/batch-predictions/prediction.results-*-of-NNNNN`
3. Cloud function is [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) to parse and insert the results to BigQuery. [This Medium post](https://medium.com/@asajharland/effective-data-loading-with-bigquery-batch-loading-flat-files-bf2fd0ebb325) explains how to this up setup